# Start Cell with Prefixed Equality Sign in LibreOffice Calc

Tags: text, libreoffice-calc

In MS Excel you can control cell contents starting with an equality sign by prefixing with a single quote:

```
'= some text
```

This prevents interpretation as formula and the single quote is not displayed.

I know, I could achieve that by a formula, however, I do not like this approach:

```
="= sometext"
```

Is there some equivalent to the MS Excel prefix or something similar in LibreOffice as well?

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps starting with a space would serve, though 'visible' in the sense that doing so increases indentation.

Comment: Many thanks to your answer. As you correctly mention, it does increase indentation. Thus it is not a real solution, however, it's a reasonable quick'n'dirty workaround in many cases. Nevertheless +1 for your suggestion.